How to construct a not self-intersecting polygon given its vertices?

Given $n\ge3$ points on the plane, describe a method to construct a polygon using them as vertices, so that the polygon is not self intersecting. (The polygon need not be convex)

The existence of such a polygon is evident: consider the polygon with shortest perimeter.
The problem here is to indicate a constructive method. Here is my idea, although it is not complete.
First, we take the convex hull of the given points. Next, we take the convex hull of the points inside the previous convex hull, and so on, until we partition the points into several layers of convex hulls, having no more than $2$ points left. For example,
Now we need to link these convex hulls. A possible way to do this would be to adjust segments in the following way,
In order to avoid causing self-intersection, the two segments we join need to be "close together". Here is where I am stuck. I cannot find a rigorous way of stating what is meant by "close together", and a proof of why it really works.

What is your definition of a polygon? In particular, does it have to be connected? Did you forget to assume that these points are not collinear? In any case, google "polygonalization."

I suggest you another method, simple, more direct.
Step 1 : you search the middle of your points $(x_M= avg(x_i), y_M=avg(y_i))$
You can choose any other point, but I suggest this one, instead of any random process.
Step 2 : you consider this point is the new origin of the plan, so each point is now $P_i(x_i-x_M, y_i-y_M)$
You can calculate the angle between the horizontal axis and the line $MP_i$
You can sort all points based on this angle. Now, you have your polygone, by joining all consecutive vertices.
